# Highcharts stacked bar chart - how to get the stacks values

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, bar-chart

I have created an highcharts stacked bar chart, but when the data is skewed, the bars are not visible or the numbers overlap, as shown in below image.

[image]

I have seen many posts, but there is no out of the box solution for this, so i am making my custom solution.

I am setting a default height of 150 if the y value is less than 150.

[image]

This solution works, but the total of the bars now is shown to be 300 instead of the actual original value. How can i change the total stacklabel value on my own? I am unable to find a way to do that.

Here is the code to change the height to default values. I am storing the actual value in realValue variable in the point object.

```
chartOptions = {
        type: CHARTING.CHART_OPTIONS.TYPE.COLUMN,  
        // On chart load, apply custom logic
        events : {
            load: function () {
                var chart = this,
                    minColHeightVal = 150;

                chart.series.forEach(function (s) {
                    s.points.forEach(function (p) {

                        if (p.y < minColHeightVal) {
                            p.update({
                                y: minColHeightVal,
                                realValue: p.y
                            }, false);
                        }
                    });
                });

           // How to iterate over the bars here and sum the actual value? i.e. point.realValue and set the stacklabel?


                chart.redraw();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post a [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use `minPointLength` option? It may be a simpler solution in your case: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.minPointLength

However, using your code to get the wanted result, use `stackLabels.formatter` function:

```
        formatter: function() {
            var series = this.axis.series,
                x = this.x,
                sum = 0;

            series.forEach(function(s) {
                if (s.points && s.points[x]) {
                    sum += s.points[x].realValue ? s.points[x].realValue : s.points[x].y
                }
            });

            return sum;
        }
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/uocdykbL/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.stackLabels.formatter